# Finding duplicates of emails at domain level

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

Need some formula help with the following  -

I want to compile a list of same domain name emails. Sample sheet here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BAB9YyPbvDgNzbT-tx-JoOHZDThcAdkX8GKBBQ5AeVo/edit?usp=sharing

**My Current State:**
I have 2 email lists list "A" of 200 emails of different people and list "B" with 2000 email ids of different people.

**I'd like to find which emails (at domain level) in list "A" are in the larger list "B"**

**Eg**: So if list "A" has emails - ee@yahoo.com, jd@123.com, abc@gmail.com and list "B"  bc@xy.com, tt@gt.com, rf@gmail.com,  tt@123.com,  I want to find out through **the domain level** (@gmail/yahoo etc) how many of list A are in list B. I don't want to find exact matches

What formula do I use? Can I use the **QUERY** function here??  if I can please aid in understanding how.

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: I see there on the example file a sheet **Ben_Example_Sheet1** that has the correct conditional formatting for this. Anything wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to pick out duplicate at a domain level.

```
=filter(
         A2:A6,
         ArrayFormula(
              REGEXMATCH(
                     A2:A6,
                     join("|",unique(ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B11,"@(.*)"))))
                       )
                   )
)
```

First I used `regextract` to extract the domain of `Col B`and join them with a pipe `|` to create a regexp.
Then filter `col A` with the array that has been created with `regexmatch + arrayformula`